# How to move issues from Google Code to Phabricator

Tags: data-migration, google-code, phabricator

Google Code is [shutting down](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html) so I want to move [my 2500 issues](http://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/list) to [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) (hosted at [Phoreplay](https://phoreplay.com)).

While there are moving procedure for Github and others, I did not manage to find similar tools for Phabricator.

How to move issues from Google Code to Phabricator?
Only issues, not wiki/code/downloads/etc.

*Note: I use Phabricator instead of Github because it fits [my requirements](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17909/issue-tracker-with-multi-criteria-sorting-alternative-to-google-code) better.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preliminary note if you wish to keep tasks IDs**

Migrations project could be facilitated if we can temporarily edit the Maniphest application code, so as you aren't in control of your installation, this is difficult to offer a clean solution to get consistent ID. So, first, you should be in control of your installation.

Such migration code has been written by the Blender project: [here their repository](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/phabricator.git/shortlog/refs/heads/blender-migration) at import moment.

**The steps**

1. Export Google code tasks in CSV or JSON format
2. Run a Phabricator script to import them, or, call the API conduit

**Export**

Google provides [some tools to perform the migration](https://code.google.com/p/support-tools/source/browse/#git%2Fgooglecode-issues-exporter). These tools include a issues.py script to parse issues on Google code.

With that, you can dump your issues in a workable format, for example JSON to store an array of comments.

**Import through API (best for smallest tasks, without comments)**

You could use the API and call through conduit [maniphest.createtask](https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/maniphest.createtask/). But this is not really convenient, as it's not the easiest way to add comments, closes the issue, etc.

**Import through a script**

This is probably the most interesting way to import the tasks, and this is the solution offering the maximal flexibility.

Here the skeleton of such script I drafting from the Blender code and some of my internal codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$root = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once $root . '/scripts/__init_script__.php';

/**
 * Represents a task importable into Phabricator
 */
class LegacyTask {
    private $id;
    private $title;
    //... other tasks properties, depending the Google Code fields

    public function importIntoPhabricator () {
        $projects = ......... // we need an array with one or more PHIDs, according what you created

        $task = ManiphestTask::initializeNewTask($reporter);
        $task->setTitle($title);
        $task->attachProjectPHIDs($projects);
        $task->setDescription($this->description);
        $task->setPriority($this->priority);
        $task->setOverrideID($this->id); //This is the method you want to borrow to the Blender migration code
        $task->save();

        //Initial transaction
        $changes = [
            ManiphestTransaction::TYPE_STATUS => ManiphestTaskStatus::STATUS_OPEN,
            PhabricatorTransactions::TYPE_VIEW_POLICY => 'public'
        ];
        self::applyTransactionsForChanges($task, $changes);

        //Closes task
        if ($this->closed) {
            $status = ... //ManiphestTaskStatus::STATUS_CLOSED_RESOLVED
            self::closeTask($task, $status);
        }

        //Project transaction
        self::associateTaskToProject($task, $projects);

        //Adds comments
        //...
    }

    static public function getTransactions ($changes) {
        $transactions = [];
        $template = new ManiphestTransaction();
        foreach ($changes as $type => $value) {
            $transaction = clone $template;
            $transaction->setTransactionType($type);
            if ($type == PhabricatorTransactions::TYPE_EDGE) {
                $transaction->setMetadataValue('edge:type', PhabricatorProjectObjectHasProjectEdgeType::EDGECONST);
            }
            $transaction->setNewValue($value);
            $transactions[] = $transaction;
        }

        return $transactions;
    }

    static public function applyTransactionsForChanges ($task, $changes) {
        $transactions = self::getTransactions($changes);
        self::applyTransactions($task, $transactions);
    }

    static public function applyTransactions ($task, $transactions) {
        $editor = id(new ManiphestTransactionEditor())
            ->setActor(self::getReporterUser())
            ->setContentSource(self::getContentSource())
            ->setContinueOnNoEffect(true)
            ->applyTransactions($task, $transactions);
    }

    static function associateTaskToProject($task, $projects) {
        $project_type = PhabricatorProjectObjectHasProjectEdgeType::EDGECONST;
        $transactions = [
            id(new ManiphestTransaction())
                ->setTransactionType(PhabricatorTransactions::TYPE_EDGE)
                ->setMetadataValue('edge:type', $project_type)
                ->setNewValue([
                    '=' => array_fuse($projects)
                ])
        ];
        self::applyTransactions($task, $transactions);
    }

    /**
     * Closes the task
     */
    static public function closeTask ($task, $status) {
        $changes = [
            ManiphestTransaction::TYPE_STATUS => $status
        ];
        self::applyTransactionsForChanges($task, $changes);
    }
}
```

Close status are documented [here](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/master/src/applications/maniphest/constants/ManiphestTaskStatus.php).

It works best.

Ask your core developers and top reporters if any to create an account, try to map their users, and for everyone else, attribute issues and comments to a bot account created for the migration.